# Restricting Wordpress Database Access to Certain Roles

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, permissions

I am creating a plug-in and have written a few custom database tables for which I only want certain roles to access. For example, subscribers should have access permissions (read, write, edit, delete) to only Table-A and no access permissions for Table-B or Table-C.

Is there a way to restrict which roles can access certain database tables? If not, what are the alternatives?

Thank you.

Comment: Wrap the db-calls in role-checks.